# Create new array depending on key

Tags: php, arrays

My array is like that:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [des_id] => 1
            [des_name] => bagan
            [tran_id] => 1
            [tran_name] => private
            [tran_image] => 1251961905A1.jpg
            [type] => car
            [troute_id] => 10
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [des_id] => 1
            [des_name] => bagan
            [tran_id] => 2
            [tran_name] => express
            [tran_image] => bus3.jpg
            [type] => car
            [troute_id] => 13
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [des_id] => 1
            [des_name] => bagan
            [tran_id] => 3
            [tran_name] => MyanmarTrain
            [tran_image] => Burma-Gorteikviaduct.jpg
            [type] => train
            [troute_id] => 16
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [des_id] => 1
            [des_name] => bagan
            [tran_id] => 4
            [tran_name] => Ayeyarwaddy Cruise
            [tran_image] => boat-ChutzpahToo1.jpg
            [type] => cruise
            [troute_id] => 22
        )

)
```

I want to change that array like that depending on key['type']. If array key['type'] are same, I want to change array like that:

```
Array
(
   [car] => Array(
        [0]=>Array
                (
                    [des_id] => 1
                    [des_name] => bagan
                    [tran_id] => 1
                    [tran_name] => private
                    [tran_image] => 1251961905A1.jpg
                    [type] => car
                    [troute_id] => 10
                ),
        [1] => Array
                (
                    [des_id] => 1
                    [des_name] => bagan
                    [tran_id] => 2
                    [tran_name] => express
                    [tran_image] => bus3.jpg
                    [type] => car
                    [troute_id] => 13
                )
            ),
   [train]=>Array(
             [0] => Array
                (
                    [des_id] => 1
                    [des_name] => bagan
                    [tran_id] => 3
                    [tran_name] => MyanmarTrain
                    [tran_image] => Burma-Gorteikviaduct.jpg
                    [type] => train
                    [troute_id] => 16
                )
   [cruise]=>Array(
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [des_id] => 1
                    [des_name] => bagan
                    [tran_id] => 4
                    [tran_name] => Ayeyarwaddy Cruise
                    [tran_image] => boat-ChutzpahToo1.jpg
                    [type] => cruise
                    [troute_id] => 22
                )
        )
    )
)
```

what I mean is that if key['type'] is car, I want to create car array or if the type is train I want to create train array or if the type is cruise I want to create cruise array. I don't know how to loop the array. Anyone please help me. Thanks a lot!

Comment: You can't do it the way you want, as the array keys have to be unique, otherwise you have no way to differentiate between one key or the other. Then there's no way to access a specific key's data successfully.

Comment: @Thyu Can you please explain more clearly what you really want to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a simple way to do it: loop over the data, and just append to the subarray matching the `type` value:

```
// starting data
$starting_array = array (
    0 => array (
            'des_id' =>  1,
            'des_name' =>  'bagan',
            'tran_id' =>  1,
            'tran_name' =>  'private',
            'tran_image' =>  '1251961905A1.jpg',
            'type' =>  'car',
            'troute_id' =>  10
        ),
    1 => array (
            'des_id' =>  1,
            'des_name' =>  'bagan',
            'tran_id' =>  2,
            'tran_name' =>  'express',
            'tran_image' =>  'bus3.jpg',
            'type' =>  'car',
            'troute_id' =>  13
        ),
    2 => array (
            'des_id' =>  1,
            'des_name' =>  'bagan',
            'tran_id' =>  3,
            'tran_name' =>  'MyanmarTrain',
            'tran_image' =>  'Burma-Gorteikviaduct.jpg',
            'type' =>  'train',
            'troute_id' =>  16
        ),
    3 => array (
            'des_id' =>  1,
            'des_name' =>  'bagan',
            'tran_id' =>  4,
            'tran_name' =>  'Ayeyarwaddy Cruise',
            'tran_image' =>  'boat-ChutzpahToo1.jpg',
            'type' =>  'cruise',
            'troute_id' =>  22
        )
);

// initialize the result array
$result = array();

// loop over the starting array
foreach($starting_array as $entry) {
    // make sure the result array has a key matching this item's type
    if(!array_key_exists($entry['type'], $result)) { 
        $result[ $entry['type'] ] = array();
    }
    // add this item to the result array
    $result[ $entry['type'] ][] = $entry;
}

// this is just for testing, so you can verify the output matches your desired result
echo "<pre>";
var_dump($result);
echo "</pre>";
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, Ed Cottrell. It's ok now! :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php

$tempArr = Array
    (
        Array(
        "des_id" => 1,
        "des_name" => "bagan",
        "tran_id" => 1,
        "tran_name" => "private",
        "tran_image" => "1251961905A1.jpg",
        "type" => "car",
        "troute_id" => 10
    ),
    Array
        (
        "des_id" => 1,
        "des_name" => "bagan",
        "tran_id" => 2,
        "tran_name" => "express",
        "tran_image" => "bus3.jpg",
        "type" => "car",
        "troute_id" => 13
    ),
    Array
        (
        "des_id" => 1,
        "des_name" => "bagan",
        "tran_id" => 3,
        "tran_name" => "MyanmarTrain",
        "tran_image" => "Burma-Gorteikviaduct.jpg",
        "type" => "train",
        "troute_id" => 16
    ),
    Array
        (
        "des_id" => 1,
        "des_name" => "bagan",
        "tran_id" => 4,
        "tran_name" => "Ayeyarwaddy Cruise",
        "tran_image" => "boat-ChutzpahToo1.jpg",
        "type" => "cruise",
        "troute_id" => 22
    )
        );

        $resultArr = array();

        foreach($tempArr as $tempKey=>$temp)
        {
            if(!array_key_exists($temp['type'], $resultArr))
            {
                $resultArr[$temp['type']] = array();
            }        
            $resultArr[$temp['type']][] = $temp;
        }

        echo '<pre>';
        print_r($resultArr);
?>
```

This is working fine .....